How to Mock S3ClientInterface with PHPUnit 10+
So this question has been asked here before - How to Mock Aws\S3\S3Client for phpunit // how to mock magic methods but the answer there is no longer valid because addMethods was deprecated in PHPUnit 10.
So the question remains - how do I mock an S3 client in a unit test in modern PHPUnit 10 / 11?
It refuses to mock methods that don't exist and the vast majority of methods including getObject are magic methods that don't actually exist.
$s3 = $this->getMockBuilder(S3ClientInterface::class)
    ->getMock();

$s3->expects($this->once())->method('doesObjectExistV2')->with(
    $this->equalTo('MockBucket'),
    $this->equalTo('mockObjects/2d/cf90910456ce55e673dab13a76a3dfd8197aa7'),
)->willReturn(true);

$s3->expects($this->once())->method('getObject')->with($this->equalTo([
    'Bucket' => 'MockBucket',
    'Key'    => 'mockObjects/2d/cf90910456ce55e673dab13a76a3dfd8197aa7',
]))->willReturn([ 'Body' => 'foo' ]);

The only thing I have gotten to work is mocking the __call method - but that is very awkward especially trying to test multiple calls to separate methods.
I assume there has to be a better way knowing how popular the AWS SDK is.

Don’t Mock Types You Don’t Own. You should create an abstraction layer between your business implementation and the S3 client (aws-sdk). You can then mock this abstraction layer. For an integration test against an S3, for example, you can use adobe/s3mock.

Hmm... So for context this is actually the test of an abstraction layer, and I am just trying to upgrade phpunit. The assertions in that article to me smells a lot like testing the library rather than unit testing our code. I need to ponder a bit.

But to me it looks like you are trying to mock the AWS SDK.

I am trying to mock the AWS SDK, to test our AWS SDK abstraction layer.
